# Optimal method to remove part of array in python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list:
a=[1,2,3,4,5,-1,5,1,1,-1]
I want to remove all elements before the first encountered negative number, I have no way of knowing the index of the number. The resultant list should be:
a=[-1,5,1,1,-1]

I have a code like:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,-1,5,1,1,-1]
while a[0] > 0 :
    a.pop(0)
print(a)
```

This code does produce the desired output but
Is there any way I can do this without iterating? Use of numpy arrays is welcome.

Comment: NameError: `i` - code does not run. Please make it a [mre]. Generally iterating a list and modifying it at the same time leads to desaster.

Comment: Your code does NOT run perfectly:  `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: You should try your pefectly running solution with `a = [1,2,3,4,-1,5,1,1,-1]` - deleting while iterating == desaster :)

Comment: @PatrickArtner you are right, it does not work.

Comment: Without numpy: `a[:] = list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x>=0, a))`

Comment: Unless you start with an array, a list solution might be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is incomplete, however this does delete all the elements of a numpy array before a negative one without using loops.

```
import numpy  as np
aa = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, 4, 5])
print(aa)

i = np.argmax(aa<0)
print(i)

aa = np.delete(aa, np.s_[:i])
print(aa)
```

Comment: May I inquire as to why the `np.delete` part is necessary? Just curious to know, thanks in advance!

Comment: Not exactly, a slicing also works as numpy.delete is not inplace operation.

Comment: I was wondering if using `np.delete` reduces space or time complexity, but I guess the gains are marginal. Thanks for the elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

Your code operates on a normal list - not a numpy array.

You can simply loop through the list up to the first negative and then list-slice your data:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,-1,5,1,1,-1]

for idx, value in enumerate(a):
    if value < 0: 
        a = a[idx:]
        break

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[-1, 5, 1, 1, -1]
```

Comment: I expect this to be fastest

Answer (score 1):

Using NumPy:

```
np_a = np.asarray(a)
np_a[np.argmax(np_a < 0):]
```

First, we convert the Python list `a` into a NumPy array to allow for vectorized operations. Then, we use the `argmax` operation to find the first index where `np_a < 0`. In this case, `np.argmax(np_a < 0)` will simply return 5, the index of the element that is the first occurrence of a negative value.

All we have to do then, is to slice the array so that we get all elements starting from index 5.